# Empty Boot folder on chroot Debian

Tags: debian, livecd, chroot, debian-jessie, debootstrap

I have wanted to create a custom livecd of Debian. I created a basic Debian (jessie) with debootstrap and began to configuring it. When I wanted to get vmlinuz and initrd files, I could not find them inside the folder 'Boot'. Is there something I have to install to generate them? or Are they supposed to be there initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve this problem (I am not sure if it is the proper way but it worked):

First I do a search:

```
$apt-cache search linux-image
```

I have found that I need a linux-image to get kernel and models. Actually it helps me to get vmlinuz and initrd files.

The command result gives me this:

```
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-586 - Header files for Linux 3.16.0-4-586
...
linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae - Linux 3.16 for modern PCs
...
linux-image-amd64 - Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

Then all I do pick the desired image which is "**linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae**" in my case. It is in arch i386 and for modern PCs(686 indicates i386 and pae is related with the modern PCs).

I install my linux-image package with the suggestions:

```
$apt-get install linux-image-3.16.0-4-686-pae
```

Now I have these files in my boot folder:

- System.map-3.16.0-4-686-pae
- config-3.16.0-4-686-pae
- **initrd.img-3.16.0-4-686-pae**
- **vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-686-pae**

Now I have my initrd and vmlinuz files.